# Is it possible to use Npgsql to connect to PostgreSQL from SSRS?

Tags: npgsql

I know that Npgsql is not and OLEDB connector. But it's an ADO.NET one.

I tried to set it up to make it a new type of Data Source for connection to Postgres (on the same level with ODBC, OLEDB or Microsoft connectors).

What I did:

1. I registered it via gacutil in Global Assembly Cache
2. I updated machine.config file both for x86 and x64 (  system.data - DbProviderFactories):

   ```
      <add name="Npgsql Data Provider" invariant="Npgsql"
   ```

   description=".Net Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL"
   type="Npgsql.NpgsqlFactory, Npgsql, Version=8.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,
   PublicKeyToken=5d8b90d52f46fda7" />

But I don't see ".Net Framework Data Provider for PostgreSQL" in the Type list of Data Source.

What I did wrong and how to make a connection to Postgre using Npgsql from the SSRS project?

Here is my list of Types:
[image: Shared Data Source Properties]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for the Npgsql MSI installed, which does the necessary installation. It's recommended to use version 4.1.x, since later versions can have various issues with assembly versions/binding redirects. Give the MSI for that version a try, it should work.

Comment: I've tried, but a new data source type hasn't appeared in the list. What else I can do?

Comment: Since you've already done some modifications to your machines.config/GAC, I'd recommend trying the MSI on a totally clean installation; this whole area is known to be very brittle, and various changes may cause drivers to not appear in the list. I'd also recommend testing whether you can see the driver e.g. in Excel, since SSRS may be filtering out drivers which are unknown to it.

Comment: Is it a problem that MSI exists only for old versions of npgsql (until 4.1)? The current version is 8.1. Does the old version suit modern SSRS? Thank you

Comment: It's unlikely that SSRS would care about Npgsql being a bit old - that version works well for PowerBI, Excel and various other applications. In any case, the first step there is to actually see it appear in the list; if you later encounter specific issues with Npgsql 4.1 (not probable), we can look into those.

Comment: I tried, I downloaded MSI for version 4.1.8, but nothing.
What was the initial configuration:
- Visual Studio Community 2022 with toolsets "SQL Server Data Tools" and ".NET Framework development tools"
- Microsoft Reporting Services Projects 2022

So, I've installed Npgsql 4.1.8 with MSI installer, but nothing appeared in my "Type" list of SSRS DataSources. Screenshot is here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/d5ayr5pr6xo46x1jfe9gp/Screenshot-2024-01-14-142518.png?rlkey=37bwhk3a4bzuklonvg18aj580&dl=0
Maybe I did something wrong?

Comment: Also, one more question:
Can I use named parameters to call PostgreSQL from SSRS using Npgsql?
For instance, create a query like this:
    select "ID", "Month", "Quantity", "Desc"
        from "RptTable"
        where "Month"=@Month

Where @Month is the named parameter which will be substituted during the call from the corresponding parameter value

Comment: Npgsl supports parameters (e.g. @Month); whether SSRS supports this I cannot really say - have you tried?

Comment: I can't try, because I can't install it yet, as I described previously in this topic.
Could you help me with that? Please, look into one of my previous messages (yesterday) that started with the words "I tried, I downloaded MSI for version 4.1.8, but nothing. ".

Also, I tried to install it via nuget via .NET CLI in VS: 'dotnet add package Npgsql'.
And I've got errors (download the text file please): https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/txt84ztvnukdk1w3s9c7p/ngpsqlerr.txt?rlkey=qx6b0kxnrkk1retdvoygtb9ft&dl=0

Could you help me with installation please?

Comment: Have you tried to install the MSI on a totally clean Windows installation as I suggested above, and to check e.g. Excel as well? Those suggestions were made above.

Comment: I've just tried on my computer with MSI installation, but can't find Npgsql as a datasource for Excel. I tried to find it under Data-->GetData-->From Database and Data-->GetData-->From Other Sources, but can't find the correspondent menu items. Am I looking in the right place?
Here are screenshots: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/01cqo9tpr3srq7zwk4rui/Screenshot-2024-01-16-225338.png?rlkey=tazkz274q59ai7jtds7dxn5t9&dl=0 and https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/udkolmev4y6j43e22lc12/Screenshot-2024-01-16-225418.png?rlkey=cw8a9feo2mgrh53h2hnv8ifd1&dl=0

Comment: I've also checked the VisualStudio file with extension list: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Community\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\SSRS\RSReportDesigner.config. 
This file doesn't contain anything form npgsql in the list of data extensions. You can see the full file here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/x3m44jmyqkmxclmr2efqa/RSReportDesigner.config?rlkey=ocvhhja4zdy35daum06ve18of&dl=0. 
So, it looks that your MSI installer is not working. What can I do wrong? Or is it a bug?
 Thank you

Comment: Shay, could you, please, help me with my questions? We are eager to use npgsql in our projects, but can't make it work. Thank you very much!

Comment: I honestly don't know what else I can say - I know of many users who installed the Npgsql MSI (4.1.x or 4.0.x) and could successfully saw Npgsql show up in the database list. I'd again recommend trying that - especially with 4.0.x - on a totally clean machine to ensure there's no leftover state interfering.

Comment: Beyond that I don't know how I can help.

Comment: I did, and the result is the same. PostgreSQL has not appeared in Excel in the "From Database" list. 
At the same time, npgsql exists in the GAC cache and machine config (both in C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config and C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config files).
Here are the screenshots and files: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/rf21idbjy7f54y8wl0nzm/h?rlkey=0oj01tgms2gs64tfgs22523zb&dl=0.
And, the same, nothing in RSReportDesigner.config :(
What else I can do?

Comment: I also tried it on 2 different computers of my friends, and the result was the same - nothing has appeared in Excel. But they've got changes in machine.config. Here are the data from one of 2 computers: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fo/q8efbtl8z4y93jztmk0im/h?rlkey=gpa5i9os8a1t266r47fe9yygu&dl=0

Comment: Hello Shay,
So, after I tried on 2 of my computers and 2 computers of my friends, I got a totally clean computer with a clean Windows, installed Excel there, and then installed npgsql. npgsql controls have not appeared in Excel. I used version 4.0.10. Then I installed SSRS and haven't seen a new datasource type in Microsoft Visual Studio as well.
So, for 5 different computers, I haven't succeeded with npgsql installation. It looks like the installer doesn't work at all :(
Could you please help me? I spent so much time without any success. What else can I do to my npgsql working?